# CvInvoke.Undistort Is making the image more distorted, not less

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

My first time working with OpenCV. The code below uses the Emgu package, but I've also tried it using OpenCVSharp and have got exactly the same results.

I am calibrating the camera using 6 chessboard photos, then using the calibration to Undistort an image. The test image is a photo of some squared paper. The camera really isn't very distorted - I can't tell that it is distorted by eye, only when I draw a straight line over the lines in a paint program.

However - the resulting image comes out way more distorted than the original - adding a lot of barrel distortion.

When I run the commented out lines, the "DrawChessboardCorners" show that it is identifying the points perfectly.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Size patternSize = new Size(9, 6);
            List<VectorOfPointF> ListOfCornerPoints = new List<VectorOfPointF>();
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\Simon\Dropbox\Apps\OpenCVPlay\Image Processing\Chessboard Pattern Photos With Pixel");

            Size calibrationImageSize = new Size(0,0) ;

            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                VectorOfPointF corners = new VectorOfPointF();
                var calibrationImage = new Image<Rgb, byte>(file.FullName);

                bool find = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(calibrationImage, patternSize, corners, CalibCbType.AdaptiveThresh | CalibCbType.FilterQuads);

                //CvInvoke.DrawChessboardCorners(calibrationImage, patternSize, corners, find);
                //calibrationImage.Save(@"Z:\Simon\Dropbox\Apps\OpenCVPlay\Image Processing\Chessboard Pattern Photos With Pixel\test\" + file.Name);

                ListOfCornerPoints.Add(corners);

                calibrationImageSize = calibrationImage.Size;
            }

            PointF[][] arrayOfCornerPoints = ListOfCornerPoints.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();

            var modelPoints = CreateModelPoints(ListOfCornerPoints.Count, patternSize.Width, patternSize.Height);

            var arrayOfModelPoints = modelPoints.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();

            Matrix<double> cameraDistortionCoeffs = new Matrix<double>(5, 1);
            Matrix<double> cameraMatrix = new Matrix<double>(3, 3);

            Mat[] rotationVectors;
            Mat[] translationVectors;

            CvInvoke.CalibrateCamera(
                arrayOfModelPoints,
                arrayOfCornerPoints,
                calibrationImageSize,
                cameraMatrix,
                cameraDistortionCoeffs,
                CalibType.Default,
                new MCvTermCriteria(),
                out rotationVectors,
                out translationVectors);

            var imageToProcess = new Image<Rgb, byte>(@"Z:\Simon\Dropbox\Apps\OpenCVPlay\Image Processing\Test data\squarePaper.jpg");
            Rectangle Rect2 = new Rectangle();
            var newCameraMatrix = CvInvoke.GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, cameraDistortionCoeffs, calibrationImageSize, 1, imageToProcess.Size, ref Rect2, true);

            Image<Rgb, byte> processedImage = imageToProcess.Clone();
            CvInvoke.Undistort(imageToProcess, processedImage, cameraMatrix, cameraDistortionCoeffs);

            processedImage.Save(@"Z:\Simon\Dropbox\Apps\OpenCVPlay\Image Processing\Test data\squarePaperFixed.jpg");

        }



        static List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>> CreateModelPoints(int length, int chessboardCols, int chessboardRows)
        {
            var modelPoints = new List<List<MCvPoint3D32f>>();
            for (var k = 0; k < length; k++)
            {
                var chessboard = new List<MCvPoint3D32f>();
                for (var y = 0; y < chessboardRows; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < chessboardCols; x++)
                    {
                        chessboard.Add(new MCvPoint3D32f(x, y, 0));
                    }
                }
                modelPoints.Add(chessboard);
            }
            return modelPoints;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please include your input images?

Comment: Yes, sorry - the chessboard pattern: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6igpfe6p9zeh5vq/AABzk5Qjph3CjBoH6p0EBeSVa?dl=0

Comment: And the photo of the squared paper: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap00xudcqibxx95/squarePaper.jpg?dl=0

Thank you!